# using jquery 1.4.4 dialog feature in jquery 1.3.2..!

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

Actually in my .net mvc application's Master page i have placed the jquery 1.3.2 js. Now when i open the page in which i have to use Dialog feature of jquery 1.3.2+. How can i do that?..  when i include it in my content page will the jquery 1.3.2+ will override jquery 1.3.2 file?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean jQuery UI?
In which case you will need to include jQuery 1.3.2 or a newer version, as well as jQuery UI 1.8.9

You can replace jQuery 1.3.2 with 1.4.4 and it should all still work.

I would remove jQuery 1.3.2 and put jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.9 both in the master page

Having two versions of jQuery on one page will cause an untold amount of trouble

Comment: actually removing  Jquery 1.3.2 with 1.4.4 is creating problem. Actually i am using flexigrid of Jquery version 1.3.2 and the dialog of new jquery so they are conflicting.

Comment: I believe the current version of Flexigrid works with JQuery 1.4